# How do I output a superscript 2 from a helper in Rails 3.2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I would like to output a string from a helper like '30 Meters2' (but with a superscript 2).

The HTML entity for a superscript 2 is ² so I thought something like this would work:

```
"30 Meters " + raw("&sup2;")
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I do this?

Here's the entire method:

```
  def area_conversion(feet, project)
    if project.metric
      "#{(feet * 0.0929).round} Meters" + raw("&sup2;")
    else
      "#{feet} sq. ft. "
    end
  end
```

Using html_safe doens't seem to work either:

```
  def area_conversion(feet, project)
    if project.metric
      "#{(feet * 0.0929).round} Meters" + "&sup2;".html_safe
    else
      "#{feet} sq. ft. "
    end
  end
```

Comment: I guess you have to define the whole string as `html_safe`. When you merge a safe string with an unsave one it gets unsafe.

Comment: You're exactly right.  I had to make both strings html_safe to work.  If you want to edit your answer accordingly, I'll be happy to accept it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to declare the whole string as `html_safe` because a safe string merged with a unsafe string gets unsafe again. In your case it should be save because a string multiplied by a float is empty, so nobody can not put dangerous code into your string here.
So this:

```
"#{(feet * 0.0929).round} Meters&sup2;".html_safe
```

should be fine.

Comment: useful,but how come it works for sup but not sub,I get string "I&sub2;" instead..

Comment: I do not think that there is a `&sub2;` HTML entity. Try something like `&#x2082;` instead.